# Android set top box development

Tags: android, google-tv, iptv, television

Has anybody experiences with Android IPTV set-top-boxes software development? Do we need to use Google TV add-on? Can we install application outside of the Market Place? Do current STBs allow the 3rd party applications installations?

I was checking several developers web pages and there were not any information which puts together the Android OS development and STBs.

There should be many specific problems not known on mobile world (media players, remote controls, etc.)

Promising devices are:

o   http://www.echostar-europe.com/products/ConnectedDevices/IPTV/X200.aspx

o   http://www.techcinema.com/2011/07/amex-mp-g7-android-tv.html

Regards,
STeN

Comment: Maybe you should split this question, it's very broad.

Comment: Hi, I know... But I do not know how to ask in better way, since there are no information available on the Internet on this topics.. The goal is to get some information on what is possible with market available Android based STBs. Any information is helpful.

Comment: Question 1: Do we need to use Google TV add-on to create an Android Set-Top box?

Comment: @STeN Did you find any tutorial?!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The two devices you listed do not mention Google TV on their specs, and both say they are running v2.x of Android OS.  You do not need the Google TV plugin if your target device does not support Google TV.

For these questions:

> Can we install application outside of the Market Place? Do current STBs allow the 3rd party applications installations?

You are going to have to contact each device manufacturer to find out how to deploy your application to their device, unless they specifically state they will support the Google Market.

Comment: Hi, do you have some good experience with some Android STB you can recommend?

Comment: I've only worked with Google TV on the revue and sony tv, sorry.  However, I very much like Google TV.  I highly recommend it.

Comment: Hi dar, Thanks for comments!!

Comment: By the way, did you find any good reference/site/book or tutorial for Set top boxes development using android? I am also having trouble finding one.